# how do i prevent typescript from complaining in this useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am trying to use this useEffect hook but cant fix the type constraint of typescript

```
useEffect(() => {
        const {
            isFetching: isLoading,
            isFetchingNextPage: loadingMore,
            fetchNextPage,
            hasNextPage,
            data,
            error,
        } = useProductsQuery({ limit: 20, pageParam: 1, ...query });
        if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }, [])
```

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA typescript is giving me this error 

Argument of type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
      Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Destructor'.
        Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' provides no match for the signature '(): void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never; }'.ts(2345)

Comment: you are returning an html element (the <p> elemen) in your hook! Why!!

Comment: also, please don't call another hook (`useProductsQuery`) in the effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use an effect at all:

```
 const {
            isFetching: isLoading,
            isFetchingNextPage: loadingMore,
            fetchNextPage,
            hasNextPage,
            data,
            error,
        } = useProductsQuery({ limit: 20, pageParam: 1, ...query });

...

if (error)  {
    return <p>{error.message}</p>
}

return <... non error elements />
```